# Google Analytics Content Experiments, how to setup variation for multiple pages

Tags: google-analytics, ab-testing, google-experiments

I would like to do a Test A/B, and I found I could do a test with Google Analytics Content Experiment, which looks interesting.
However all the documentation I have read the test is for static pages, for example:

www.mysite.com/products/tv.html
www.mysite.com/products/fan.html

I recently read here I could use relative url for the variation page, adding a parameter, for example:

- www.mysite.com/products/tv.html?ab=1
- www.mysite.com/products/fan.html?ab=1

The thing is I have a lot of products on my site and I would like to apply the test to all my products BUT I use a rewriting module to my product pages, because it could have categories and more, so I have clean Urls, for exmaple:

- www.mysite.com/products/informatic/computer/12
- www.mysite.com/products/informatic/computer/17
- www.mysite.com/products/cleaning/85
- www.mysite.com/products/cleaning/156
- www.mysite.com/products/informatic/software/accounting/82
- www.mysite.com/products/informatic/software/accounting/99

As you can see I have different rewriting rules, different levels depending on the category of the product (this is just an example), but my product page is just one for all the products:

- www.mysite.com/products/product.aspx?productid=$1

I wonder how could I do a test having clean urls.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: HAve you considered using a different tool?

Comment: Which tool for example? Free tool?

Comment: But do you think is not possible with GA?